# One action method route parameter causing action to be not found in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app. I have an action method where I define the verb and a route like this:

```
[HttpGet, Route("/Table_Read")]
public async Task<JsonResult> Table_Read(string tableName 
{  }
```

I call the above method from the dropdown which populates from the datasource like this:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.TaskId).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
            .DataValueField("Key")
            .DataTextField("Value")                
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("Table_Read", "standard").Data("GetSelectedId");
                });
            })
            )
```

The problem is when I have the route on the action method as `Table_Read`, the action method does not get called. And I checked the error in the developer portal and found that this action method is not found.

When I removed the `Read` from route parameter and update the route as `Table`, the action method gets called.

```
[HttpGet, Route("/Table")]
public async Task<JsonResult> Table_Read(string tableName)
{
    //....
}
```

My question is: why does adding the route name on the original action method not work? And why I must define the route because removing it did not work as well.

By the way I do not have any other action method with the same name with in this controller.

Interestingly in another controller I have the same code with the route as `Table_Read` which matches the action method name, but I do not get an error.

**Update**

I noticed that there are two controller. The first working controller from where I copied the code stopped working and started to throw http 404 errors. After noticing that, I changed the method name and route name and then both the controller action method started to work. I would not expect that behaviour but I tested multiple times and each time when the action method has the same name or route then they I am getting error on both the pages on load. I copied the error message when for each action method from different controller.

```
GET https://localhost:44313/Table_Read?table=1  //error500
```

This results in a http 500 error and doesn't show the controller name

```
GET https://localhost:44313/EAmerica/Table_Read?table=1    // 404
```

This results in a http 404 error. Notice, the above is showing the controller name

Comment: Have you tried using a route name *without* a leading `/` ? `[HttpGet, Route("Table_Read")]`

Comment: removing the / worked but not sure how.  See my updates on main post.